# freetds Class 'mssql_connect' not found

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I'm using mssql server on my php scripts. I've buy new server and getting some error about usigin freetds. I've confire and install complete freetds. I'm using tsql shell command on ssh. it's working. But when I try to on Php getting some error.

Class 'mssql_connect' not found.

sql connect page :

http://renori.net/a/giris.php

php info page :

http://renori.net/a/phpinfo.php

Cheers.

Comment: shows us the relevant code from giris.php

Comment: <?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
session_start();


$mssql_sunucu="mybigserver";
$mssql_tablo="ad_forum";
$mssql_kullanici="sa";
$mssql_parola="aa123..";
$db = new mssql_connect($mssql_sunucu,$mssql_kullanici,$mssql_parola);

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
  error_reporting(E_ALL); ob_start(); 
  session_start(); 
  $mssql_sunucu="mybigserver"; 
  $mssql_tablo="ad_forum"; 
  $mssql_kullanici="sa"; 
  $mssql_parola="aa123.."; 
  $db = mssql_connect($mssql_sunucu,$mssql_kullanici,$mssql_parola); ?>
```

Leave `new` out before `mssql_connect`